# If not-equal-to 'string' has syntax error I can't find

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, syntax-error

Below is a code that sends emails with alerts created from data in a spreadsheet.

The line `if(ce2 != 'no value'){` Has a `Syntax error` as do the following two `if` statements: `if(al2 != 'no value'){` and `if(cc2 != 'no value'){`; however, the first `if` statement, `if(ce2 != 'no value' || al2 != 'no value' || cc2 != 'no value'){`, does not. I cannot find the error. I'm sure it's something stupid I haven't clicked onto, though.

I have tried using the correct `if` statement in place of the ones with the error, but it still has the error. I have played with the positioning of the `+`'s to see if that has any effect. The function works if the `if` lines and their corresponding `}`'s are commented out. I also changed `'empty'` to `'no value'` in case that was a 'reserved' word or some such.

```
function emailAlerts() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('EmailAlerts');
  var sub = s.getRange('F5').getValue();
  var nm2 = s.getRange('C11').getValue();
  var em2 = s.getRange('D11').getValue();
  var ce2 = s.getRange('E11').getValue();
  var al2 = s.getRange('F11').getValue();
  var cc2 = s.getRange('G11').getValue();

  if(ce2 != 'no value' || al2 != 'no value' || cc2 != 'no value'){
    MailApp.sendEmail(em2, sub, '',{
      htmlBody: 'Good morning '+nm2+
      ',<br><br><b>Your alerts:</b><br><br>'+
      if(ce2 != 'no value'){
          '<b>CONTRACTS EXPIRING</b><br>'+
          ce2+'<br><br>'+
        }
        if(al2 != 'no value'){
          '<b>AUDIO LINES EXPIRING</b><br>'+
          al2+'<br><br>'+
          }
        if(cc2 != 'no value'){
          '<b>COLD CALLS TO FOLLOW UP</b><br>'+
          cc2+'<br><br>'+
          }
      'Kind regards,<br>XXX'
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because your nested if statements have code, but no semi-colon terminated expressions. You should create a string with the message you want to send, use ifs to append to it, then send the email. Something like:

```
var htmlBodyMessage = 'Good morning' + nm2;

if(ce2 != 'no value')
{
    htmlBodyMessage += 'CONTRACTS EXPIRING' + ce2;
}
if(al2 != 'no value')
{
    htmlBodyMessage += 'AUDIO LINES EXPIRING'+ al2;
}
if(cc2 != 'no value')
{
    htmlBodyMessage += 'COLD CALLS TO FOLLOW UP</b><br>'+ cc2;
}

MailApp.sendEmail(em2, sub, '', { htmlBody: htmlBodyMessage });
```

Comment: Thanks. I now have the error `missing ; before statement` for the second line of code `var cc3 = s.getRange('G12').getValue();

  string htmlBodyMessage = 'Good morning' + nm2 + ',<br><br><b>YOUR ALERTS:</b><br><br>'+ ...;

if(ce2 != 'no value')`

Comment: Right, I got it to work after removing `+...` and replacing `string` with `var`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @c0de No problem, if you could click the tick mark to the left of my question so other people know this solved your problem that'd be great!